# script to print range works on one workbook, not another (ReferenceError: objectToQueryString is not defined)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm losing my mind.
I have a workbook and use a script I got from here to print various reports (link to original at top of script). Works great. Started another workbook for another project and literally copy/pasted the script and I get an error that my variable is not defined. But it looks like it is!

[Here's a copy](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vJh6C58GiKema-lAvYtVHULV7kXzI7g52QDYwd2WO-Y/edit#gid=989316086) of the problem spreadsheet. Trying to run the code printFriday. printSaturday is in the menu but I haven't done the script yet because Friday won't work. I even changed the print range to match the copied from code in case my column and row numbers (of the data I want to print) were causing a problem.

[Here's the code](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1TyEwOGSZLIntmTxgevtx3TNLLB9hYgtE8rRqO8DocjE/edit) I use in the other spreadsheet that works. I can't share that workbook as too much personal information.

Please ignore the notes I make for myself as scripting isn't really my thing.

Help? What am I missing?
Thanks,

Comment: Now, I noticed your script from your showing URL. When I saw your script, it seems that the function of `objectToQueryString` is not declared. I think that this is the reason for your issue of `ReferenceError: objectToQueryString is not defined`. How about adding the function? Your `objectToQueryString` comes from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59085050)?

Comment: Sorry to take so long to get back to this but thanks, that little bit of code did the trick!