# Sheets Scripts- Save As PDF- Pull File Name from Cell

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Objective: Automatically insert file name for Download as PDF.

I have put together a script that opens a print preview screen that allows me to print the selected cells. It also has a download button that allows me to download the preview as a PDF.  I would like to be able to set the file name from the combination of 3 cells. Name ('C6:J6') + Date('L54:N54') + Time ('S54:U54'). These cells are all on the same sheet that is being printed. I am at a loss as to how to do this.

Below is my script and a screenshot of my print preview screen. Circled is the file name that I would like to replace and the download button that opens the standard download file screen.  Thank you in advance!

```
//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58627501/how-to-print-sheet-range-using-gs-script-in-google-sheets
//https://xfanatical.com/blog/print-google-sheet-as-pdf-using-apps-script/

function printCQF() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1:AN59').activate();
  spreadsheet.setCurrentCell(spreadsheet.getRange('AN59'));
  printSelectedRange();
};

var PRINT_OPTIONS = {
  'size': 0,              // paper size. 0=letter, 1=tabloid, 2=Legal, 3=statement, 4=executive, 5=folio, 6=A3, 7=A4, 8=A5, 9=B4, 10=B
  'fzr': false,           // repeat row headers
  'portrait': true,       // false=landscape
  'scale': 3,             //1= Normal 100% / 2= Fit to width / 3= Fit to height / 4= Fit to Page
  'top_margin':0.25,      //All four margins must be set!
  'bottom_margin':0.25,   //All four margins must be set!
  'left_margin':0.2,      //All four margins must be set!
  'right_margin':0.2,     //All four margins must be set!
  'gridlines': true,      // show gridlines
  'printnotes':false,     //true/false'
  'printtitle': false,
  'sheetnames': false,
  'pagenum': 'UNDEFINED', // CENTER = show page numbers / UNDEFINED = do not show
  'attachment': false
}

var PDF_OPTS = objectToQueryString(PRINT_OPTIONS);

/*  
// Creates a custom menu.  
function onOpen(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Print...').addItem('Print selected range', 'printCQF').addToUi();
}
*/

function printSelectedRange() {
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange();
 

  var gid = sheet.getSheetId();
  var printRange = objectToQueryString({
    'c1': range.getColumn() - 1,
    'r1': range.getRow() - 1,
    'c2': range.getColumn() + range.getWidth() - 1,
    'r2': range.getRow() + range.getHeight() - 1
  });
  var url = ss.getUrl().replace(/edit$/, '') + 'export?format=pdf' + PDF_OPTS + printRange + "&gid=" + gid;

  var htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('js');
  htmlTemplate.url = url;
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlTemplate.evaluate().setHeight(10).setWidth(100), 'Print range');
}

function objectToQueryString(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).map(function(key) {
    return Utilities.formatString('&%s=%s', key, obj[key]);
  }).join('');

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to download the file using `UrlFetchApp.fetch()`, create a file based on the response for the `fetch()` using `DriveApp.createFile()`, rename it, get the URL of newly created file and set it as value of `htmlTemplate.url`.

**Replace the `printSelectedRange()` in your code with this:**

```
function printSelectedRange() {
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange();
 

  var gid = sheet.getSheetId();
  var printRange = objectToQueryString({
    'c1': range.getColumn() - 1,
    'r1': range.getRow() - 1,
    'c2': range.getColumn() + range.getWidth() - 1,
    'r2': range.getRow() + range.getHeight() - 1
  });
  var url = ss.getUrl().replace(/edit$/, '') + 'export?format=pdf' + PDF_OPTS + printRange + "&gid=" + gid;

  var params = {method:"GET",headers:{"authorization":"Bearer "+ ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};
  
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params).getBlob();

  var name = sheet.getRange('C6:J6').getDisplayValue();
  var date = sheet.getRange('L54:N54').getDisplayValue();
  var time = sheet.getRange('S54:U54').getDisplayValue();
  var filename = name + "-" +  date + "-" + time;

  //create new file on drive
  var newFile = DriveApp.createFile(response).setName(filename);
  
  var htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('js');
  htmlTemplate.url = newFile.getUrl();
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlTemplate.evaluate().setHeight(10).setWidth(100), 'Print range');
}
```

**Example Output:**

[image]

**Note:** If you want to remove the generated file after you print it, you can add `newFile.setTrashed(true);` at the end of `printSelectedRange()` function. This will move the files to trash. Files in trash will be automatically deleted after 30 days.

### References:

- [DriveApp.createFile(blob)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#createfileblob)
- [UrlFetchApp.fetch()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl)
- [File.setTrashed(boolean)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#settrashedtrashed)

Comment: Thank you for the help Nikko.  When I entered the code as written I receive an error:  
ReferenceError:                                                                                              
 objectToQueryString is not defined
(anonymous) @ Print to PDF.gs:28                                                                                     
  which is referring to:                                                     
 var PDF_OPTS = objectToQueryString(PRINT_OPTIONS);

Comment: I think you deleted the `objectToQueryString()` function in your code. Just replace the content of `printSelectedRange()` with the code I provided above without changing of the other functions. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Yes, That was exactly it.  Thank you!