# printing header on Google Sheet

Tags: printing, scripting, gsheets

I've been using a script from carlesgg97 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58627501/how-to-print-sheet-range-using-gs-script-in-google-sheets). It's worked great! There's a line for a header ('fzr': false, // repeat row headers) which I finally need to use but have no idea how to define that header, or where to put it in the code.
Can anyone help?
Thanks