# AppScript to trigger the "Print" window for a fixed range

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a spreadsheet in which the range **Sheet1!B1:I34** needs to be printed very often.

Is there a way that the print window can be triggered via a script, in order to print the specific range only?

[image]

Thanks & regards

Comment: Just wondering, would you be open to considering printing a sheet instead of the specific range you are providing?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for any alternative to get this done, but the closest I got was to open up a pop-up with a PDF view of the file to print, including the desired print configuration, so you can just click the printer icon. Like this:
[image]

I did try several approaches, but neither of them allowed me to take a specific range within the sheet (even though I explicitly declared it); it just ignored it and attempted to print cells with values on them (within the declared range or not). That being said, I would like to propose a workaround.

### Workaround

Create a new dedicated sheet and add an IMPORTRANGE() formula pointing to the range you want to print using a script. Once you have the new sheet (you can have it hidden so it doesn’t clutter your worksheet), you can use the following code:

```js
var PRINT_OPTIONS = {
  'size': 7,               // paper size. 0=letter, 1=tabloid, 2=Legal, 3=statement, 4=executive, 5=folio, 6=A3, 7=A4, 8=A5, 9=B4, 10=B
  'fzr': false,            // repeat row headers
  'portrait': false,        // true= portrait format
  'fitw': true,            // fit window or actual size
  'gridlines': false,      // show gridlines
  'printtitle': false,
  'sheetnames': false,
  'pagenum': 'UNDEFINED',  // CENTER = show page numbers / UNDEFINED = do not show
  'attachment': false
}

var PDF_OPTS = objectToQueryString(PRINT_OPTIONS);

function onOpen(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Print App').addItem('Print selected range', 'printSelectedRange').addToUi();
}

function printSelectedRange() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");  //Here you can call any other sheet by adding its exact name
  var gid = sheet.getSheetId();
  var printingRange = objectToQueryString({
    'first row': 1,// first row
    'first column': 2, // first column
    'last row': 34,  //last row
    'last column': 8, // last column
  });   //This variable it does references your range B1:I34 but it continues to take any cell that's not empty 
  var url = ss.getUrl().replace(/edit$/, '') + 'export?format=pdf' +'&'+ PDF_OPTS +'&' + printingRange + "&gid=" + gid;

  var htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('window'); //here it is calling the js HTML created
  htmlTemplate.url = url;
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlTemplate.evaluate().setHeight(10).setWidth(100), 'Print range');
}

function objectToQueryString(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).map(function(key) {
    return Utilities.formatString('&%s=%s', key, obj[key]);
  }).join('');
}
```

Remember to update this section with the exact name of the sheet you created for this code:

```js
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");  //Here you can call any other sheet by adding its exact name
```

After that, you’ll need a HTML file in your App Script project, and name it ‘window’:
[image]

Once you have everything set up and have authorized the script for the first time, your spreadsheet will have a menu at the top named "Print App." It will generate the PDF URL with the printing configuration already done. Check the comments in the code if you want to change the printing preferences. If you have any questions, let me know :)

#### References

- [Import Range](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en)
- [create HTML in App Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html#create_html_files)
- Used this answer as a reference ["How to Print sheet/range using .gs script in Google Sheets?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58627501/how-to-print-sheet-range-using-gs-script-in-google-sheets/58629741#58629741)