# How to control position of printout on sheet through gs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am using Google Script and Sheets to create and print PDFs -
with major help from "[How to Print sheet/range using .gs script in Google Sheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58627501/how-to-print-sheet-range-using-gs-script-in-google-sheets)".

Can control the sheet area, margins, headers/footers, frozen areas, etc, but have not found any way to control the position of the printed range on the printsheet.

Does anyone know of a way to control horizontal and vertical position using Google Sheets?

I've tried any number of likely parameter names with no success.